# How does "Export as JPG" work in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, jpeg

In OpenOffice Writer there is no option to export a document as JPG, only export as PDF. Therefore to make an image, first I have to convert the document as pdf, then convert the PDF to JPG. But if I make the resolution of the image higher than the PDF, the image quality detoriates.

In LibreOffice Writer, there is an option to export the ODT directly to JPG. I just have to specify the resolution. But the best part is that the image quality does not detoriate.

How does LibreOffice achieve this? What does it do to maintain the quality? How can I do this outside LibreOffice?

Comment: Also posted at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/158195/how-does-export-as-jpg-work-in-libreoffice-writer/.

Answer (score 1):

The Libre Office can do this "printing" the text directly in a JPG or PDF.

If you export an archive to PDF with 300 DPI, for exemple, you're able to convert this into a JPG with max of 300 DPI without distortions. If you put 400 DPI from a 300 DPI PDF, is like you ware "stretching" the archive.

But, when you do this directly from de Libre Office, you're defining the resolution of the image, without intermediary conversions. So, if you set 900 DPI for the image, you'll can convert this in another archive with max of 900 DPI. But the same thing is applicable here, if you wants a archive with 1000 DPI from a image with only 900 DPI, there will be some distortions on the final result.

Basically, you can do the convertion directly from the Libre Office with more resolution to a JPG because the Libre Office have the "orginal file", and not a "intermediary file" like the PDF.

And sorry, but I don't know how to do this outside Libre Office, but must exists a lot of programs that do this.